# How to use dynamic url in two handlers in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url

How do I take this url

```
<a href="/item?id=%s">
```

from this handler

```
class Newest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
            items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30")

        self.response.out.write("<ol>")
        for item in items:
            self.response.out.write("""<li><a href="%s">%s</a> <br /><a href="/item?id=%s">comments</a></li><br /> """ % 
                                    (cgi.escape(item.url), cgi.escape(item.title), cgi.escape(str(item.key().id()))))
        self.response.out.write("</ol>")
```

and use it in this handler

```
class Item(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("""<p>Article title and link goes here</p>""")
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**

As suggested by [djidjadji at app engine group](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/bcc08df62f20ab04?hl=en) I changed the `url` like this:

```
class Newest(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        items = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Item ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30")
        self.response.out.write("<ol>")
        for item in items:
            self.response.out.write("""<li><a href="%s">%s</a> <br /><a href="/item/%s"><span style="color: #808080; font-size: x-small;">comments</span></a></li><br /> """ % 
                                    (cgi.escape(item.url), cgi.escape(item.title), cgi.escape(str(item.key().id()))))
        self.response.out.write("</ol>")
        self.response.out.write("</div></body></html>")
```

and `Article` handler like this:

```
class Article(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        id = int(id)        
        self.response.out.write("""<a href="/item/%s">article title</a> """ % 
                                    (id))
```

So now the url is correct. But can you help with the article title? How do I get the article title `item.title` from inside the `for` loop to the `Article` handler?

**EDIT 2**

This solves the problem. ([Thanks djidjadji](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/msg/31c20772210f2c8f?hl=en))

```
class Article(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        id = int(id)
        item = Item.get_by_id(id)

        self.response.out.write("""<a href="%s">%s</a> """ % 
                                    (cgi.escape(item.url), cgi.escape(item.title)))
```

Comment: Please read the documentation for the Request object: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html . You probably want to call self.request.get('id').

Comment: @yonran: can you elaborate a bit more. I read the referenced page but I don't see the connection. How do I form the url of the article connected to `comments`?

Comment: You should post your update as an answer to your own question, so others can benefit from it and the question appears as answered.